# Can't Promote Server to Secondary Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, delegation

We have a server running Server 2008 R2 as our primary DC. We currently don't have a secondary DC, but are trying to add one. The secondary DC we are trying to use is running Server 2012 R2 Standard.

**The Issue:**

When we try to promote the second server to a domain controller we run into an error:

```
The Active Directory Domain Services Installation Wizard was unable to
convert the computer account SERVERNAME$ to an Active Directory 
Domain Controller Account.
```

You can see a screencap here:
[image: Active Directory Error]

**What We Have Tried:**

We have tried modifying the Default Domain Controller Policy to give Delegation rights to Domain Admins.  This part works, but doesn't appear when we run `whoami /all`. Instead we get this result: `SeEnableDelegationPrivilege  Disabled`

We have also tried going into the AD Users And Computers > Computers > SERVERTOBEPROMOED.  We went to Properties>Delegation and selected `Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos Only)`.

After setting both of those, running `gpupdate /force` on both servers, and waiting 90 minutes, the `whoami /all` still shows `SeEnableDelegationPrivilege  Disabled`

Note: The `whoami /all` was run on multiple computers including the AD and the computer to be promoted, and showed the same result.

We are at a loss for what is going on here.  Rebuilding the entire AD is out of the question, but rebuilding the Default Domain Controller Policy could be on the cards, although we'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: `whoami /all still shows SeEnableDelegationPrivilege  Disabled`. That is the default state. Windows enables the privilege when needed. Is your domain controller in the Domain Controllers OU, and is the Default Domain Controllers policy and Default Domain policy applying without error as confirmed with `gpresult /h gpresult.html` ?

Comment: @GregAskew That is really good to know. We managed to fix it.  We had to drop and re-add the new server to the domain and change the Link Order on the Domain Policy. This made them apply correctly. We don't really know why it wasn't before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it!

We had to drop the server we wanted to add as a domain controller from the domain and re-add it. After dropping it, before re-adding it, we had to delete the server object from the list of domain computers.

Hopefully this could help someone else who runs into this.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that that the policy Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Enable computer and users accounts to be trusted for delegation is set on the default domain controllers OU.  Verify that the account you are using to promote the computer has this policy applied.  You can use gpresult /h report.html to verify.

Answer (score 0):

When KB5008102 (November 2021) is applied, this error will also occur if a user who is not in the "Domain Admins" global group tries to promote a domain controller.  The update blocks the UAC settings up date with a message (on the DC you are replicating from/trying to update the computer object against):

```
The security account manager blocked a non-administrator from creating an Active Directory account in this domain with mismatched objectClass and userAccountControl account type flags.

Details:

Account name: NEWDCNAME$
Account objectClass: domainDNS
userAccountControl: 8448
Caller address: xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy
Caller SID: S-1-5-21-YourAccountSID
```

Microsoft seems to have forgotten that Enterprise Admins should be considered admins.  For instance, if you are trying to promote a new DC in a child domain with an Enterprise Admin account in the parent domain, this will now fail with this update.  You have to create an account in the child domain, add it to the domain admins global group, and then do the promotion.

Comment: I've never used Domain Admins. Nearly all permissions are conferred by the domain Administrators group. Fairly sure you don't need to create an account in the child domain for that. Also the objects that require permissions can be re-ACL'd.